I am receiving an error every time I attempt to use scipy via python/ jupyter notebook,
I have never used any kind of coding before this particular class, which has only been going on for two days now, and I keep receiving this error  code (shown below) from using Scipy. I have tried downloading a different version of Scipy, 1.14.0, but anaconda would not even let me download it. I have also attempted creating a new environment only to run into a different error. I am completely clueless as to how to fix this despite researching for around an hour, any advice would be greatly appreciated.
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 from scipy.integrate import quad 
      2 def func(x):                       # quad means integrate
      3     return x**3 

    File ~\miniconda3\envs\gp\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:132
    129 from scipy.version import version as __version__
    131 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 132 from . import _distributor_init
    133 del _distributor_init
    135 from scipy._lib import _pep440

    File ~\miniconda3\envs\gp\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py:59
     57     os.chdir(libs_path)
     58     for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 59         WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     60 finally:
     61     os.chdir(owd)

    File ~\miniconda3\envs\gp\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:373, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    370 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    372 if handle is None:
--> 373     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374 else:
    375     self._handle = handle

    FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\spino\miniconda3\envs\gp\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.4HQRZL2D6UUGPVKYP75OJIKUJ77H7S4U.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.


Posting some suggestions and workarounds. These are not solutions to your borked machine; however, they may allow you to quickly continue working for now despite the hurdles you encountered with what you described in your post....
As a new learner, you'd be better off not using miniconda and just install the entire Anaconda Distribution and use that on your machine, launching from the Anaconda Navigator. You can make a new environment if it doesn't have Scipy in the base already.
I will add that since this is for a class, you really should take these issues to the instructor. I doubt they want to see you struggle alone with technical issues when the point is to cover the material for the course.
Also if this is for a class, taking time to get past this hurdle is probably not what you want to be struggling with. Fortunately, these days there are a lot of options where you can work with Scipy beyond what you have seemed to try.
Alternatives that will let you work with Scipy again
A. On your own machine
JupyterLab Desktop
An alternative is to install JupyterLab Desktop and use that since you seem to have borked your minoconda install.
Read about JupyterLab Desktop here because it's project management model is very different than Anaconda/conda.
JupyterLite
Technically the computation will be going deep in your browser if you choose to use JupyterLite. It is based on Jupyter in your browser using a special kernel (Pyodide-based) that runs 'Python' in web assembly running in your browser. There's no server involved except to hand you off the static files to get Jupyter and pyodide started in your browser. However, because you cannot use your system's normal graphical user interface to access the filesystem where the files are stored outside of the running Jupyter, I caution people to treat it as 'remote'-like. And so I'll cover it more under the remote options below.
B. Remote or 'Remote'/ Online options
These are the easiest because nothing really touches your machine's local system. Everything is in your browser. So there's 99.99999% chance nothing you do to get Jupyter running either of these two ways will mess up your system in any way. (In fact, these are great ways to test new things where you know your local system will remain how you currently have it set up, which hopefully normally is in a working state.)
The compromise is that it is temporary in a sense, JupyterLite being somewhat less-so. You have to start things back up each time and most importantly if you make anything useful download it (or 'download' in the case of JupyterLite) to your local machine's normal file storage system and keep track of where you put them to have them handy to pick back up again. In the case of JupyterLite, often you don't need to do anything because if you don't change your browser's cache the content you made in last session will be there, but being deliberate is better in the long run. Especially when you don't know exactly how soon you'll be using JupyterLite served from that location again.
The Jupyter Community offers two alternatives for 'online' use: JupyterLite, that runs in your browser using web assembly & I have mentioned already; and MyBinder-served Jupyter sessions from a remote machine with full Python kernels. Below, I cover both of these in regards to your situation with Scipy, and include current working links. Please eventually though read more about these two here, as there are possible pitfalls and workarounds that may take you a long time to find as a novice.
I mentioned the Jupyter Community offers these two. In fact, both of the two I cover here for online options are used here on the 'Try Jupyter' page to offer the interactive demos listed there. Once you read about the two I discuss below, you may be able to hover over the tiles on that page and deduce which ones are using what to offer the demos. Some, of course, say what they use outright.
MyBinder.org-served Jupyter Sessions
This would get my highest recommendation as an alternative. This will give you a typical, full Python-based kernel running on a remote virtual machine and most networking works.
Be aware though that you do lose persistence though. These session is very ephemeral and will time out without activity. There is no way to get back to the virtual machine you had, it is gone forever. It is best you always download to your local machine anything useful you make immediately. I download my notebooks very often during development or immediately after running. Then you can upload them to get started in a new session later. Fortunately, this is easy because JupyterLab lets you drag-and-drop notebook files into a fresh system from your local system by dragging them into the file navigation pane on the left and releasing the mouse.
The Binder Examples page offers a lot of basic starting points where you will get a Jupyter session without much installed. Therefore, for using Scipy in such session you have to run in the notebook %pip install scipy before getting started. However, users can set up to have many packages already installed in the session at start up, and so you are ready to run a notebook or code right away once the session spins up. I have a GitHub repo set up to specify to already install Scipy here in the session that will start up using that repo as a basis. Go there and   click on 'launch binder', or click here to get started directly, and you'll get a temporary Jupyter session on a remote machine (provided by the 'MyBinder' service) where I already set it to included Scipy installed when the session starts. It is not persistent and so if you make anything useful download it immediately. If you have notebooks for your class that you have been drafting you can upload them from your local computer using the drag-and-drop approach I discussed above.
The computational resources it offers are limited though and so you cannot do massive calculations or scale up a lot. You also may need to be patient at start up as there are limited resources. Be patient; however, also try to learn the timing for a typical start up so that you aren't stuck waiting but have a failed start-up. If it's been more than like 5 minutes, try the launch again.
JupyterLite
Caveat: JupyterLite has some rough edges and due to browser security and design and how file access & networking works when you are already in a browser some things aren't possible or don't directly translate, without some JupyterLite-specific syntax or workarounds at this time. So Pyodide is not a 100% normal Python kernel, and that sometimes makes it hard for novices who see Python code somewhere and cannot understand why it doesn't work that way in JupyterLite. The most notable example is the input() use. Scipy does indeed work though in JupyterLite in that is is listed as compatible with Pyodide here and here, but I cannot speak to all the code and conventions working in JupyterLite.
Also, it is just slower to work with. You have to be extra patient both when JupyterLite starts up a notebook and when you import a package.
Using JupyterLite at this time:
Go here (that link comes from the 'Try Jupyter' page) and you can make a new notebook or 'upload' your own. That's the same one that available from the first tile on this 'Try Jupyter' Page. You can choose the tile next to there if you prefer the Jupyter Notebook-style, document-centric flavor. I confirmed Scipy is installed already in sessions that will start up from there. Just be patient the first time you run the notebook & execute import scipy. It's slower than a typical Python kernel to start that up.
(I don't know why the demo links offered in the upper right at the JupyterLite main documentation page don't allow making a new notebook & give a read-only error. I used to reference there for users to start. At least the Try Jupyter offerings presently work to make new notebooks without issue.)
You can read more about JupyterLite on the 'Try Jupyter' page and on the official JupyterLite project page, both of which emphasize the experimental nature of it at this time.
